# Drupal fails to run update.php when new services have been introduced and depend in inactive module

Tags: 8, updating

In production environment I have an active module that in a new deployment has changes to the `mymodule.services.yml` file. This new services file points to services located in an inactive module.

I try to enable them creating a update hook in `mymodule.install` file and running update.php file without success. update.php triggers an error due to unresolvable dependencies in the active module.

Is there any way to ignore these errors and to continue with the update or is there another way to enable modules in this exact use case?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably revert the code base, then enable the inactive module, and then update the code base. Dependencies (Drupal or composer-based) need to be enabled first before updating code base.

Comment: This is difficult to do when you are using automated deployments deploying to multiple instances and you need to ensure 0 downtime. I guess that this kind of deployments will need to manually disable modules that conflict before running the deploy script

Comment: 0 downtime is not possible. Running database and entity updates should put the site into maintenance mode automatically anyway. However you can automate deployment processes by providing pre/post build steps in jenkins or what not.